# Why these simple circles in D3 are not showing?

Tags: d3.js

I am new at D3 and I am trying to run a simple [example](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/) 
So here I have the following HTML and javascript

```js
var circle = d3.selectAll('circle');

circle.style("fill", "steelblue");
circle.attr("r", 30);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="720" height="120">
  <circle cx="40" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
  <circle cx="80" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
  <circle cx="120" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
</svg>
```

If you run the code snippet. It works. But then if I copy the same code in a separate HTML and script, it just doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy them in a separate HTML and script"? You mean one html file with <script> section containing the javascript code? If you have put the javascript in a js file, did you include that js file in your html? Please clearify.

Comment: @dgg32 Yes I have a separate HTML file, that includes the d3 and also includes the javascript code in a separate js file, that I also include in the head of the HTML. I tested it with just putting a console.log('hello'); and works fine except for the d3 code.

Comment: The script include section should be after the <svg> tags. Because d3 script can't operate on something hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by separate HTML and script you meant a html file and a script file, it works for me. Maybe you forget to include the script in the html file? The script include section should be after the `<svg>` tags. Because d3 script can't operate on something hasn't been created yet.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you explain why adding the scripts at bottom will work while adding the scripts at the top it won't work?

Comment: In this case, the rendering follows the code. In other words, d3 only operates on things that are created, that is when the svg comes first. If you do the opposite however, the browser ain't going back the lines and run the script. But it is possible to do a "script first svg next", by defining all you d3 things in your script.js as a function "change()", then after the svg, you add a <script> section and in it, you call that change().

Comment: Now in my second screenshot, you see the "script first svg next" approach in action.